# Bigpipe after load event

Tags: 8, javascript

When I enable the bigpipe module most of the blocks disappear, since I use a Vue layer. I've tried the following codes but none of them have worked for me:

```
  var charging_blocs = $('[data-big-pipe-placeholder-id]').length;
  if (!charging_blocs ){
    console.log('This is executed just once, when all bigpipe blocs are loaded');
  }

  var checkReadyState = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      clearInterval(checkReadyState);
      console.log('Page is loaded.');
      /* Put your code logic here */
      (function ($, Drupal) {
       console.log('enters here');
      })(jQuery, Drupal);
    }
  }, 100);
```

Is there a js event on bigpipe to detect that all blocks have been loaded?

Comment: This is where drupal behaviours would be used https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview if you can use that in your Vue code then that would be the recommended Drupal way

Comment: No, I can't modify the vue code, cause it comes from an external service.

Comment: Is the page actually firing the AJAX request(s) to fetch the Bigpipe content? That's how the blocks get loaded.